# Add elements of XML using for-each of XSLT, only if tag value is non empty

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to do some exercise on XSLT and this is my first xslt attempt:

**I have the following xml as my input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <elementA>
        <elementB attB="valueb">
            <elementC attC="c-value">
                what I want
            </elementC>
        </elementB>
        <elementB attB="valueb">

        </elementB>
    </elementA>
</root>
```

**and the following xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/root/elementA">
        <newElement>
            <xsl:for-each select="elementB[@attB='valueb']">
                <valuef>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./elementC">
                        <xsl:value-of select=".">
                        </xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </valuef>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </newElement>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The transformed xml I get is:**

```
<newElement>
    <valuef>
           what I want
    </valuef>
    <valuef/>
</newElement>
```

I want to get rid of the empty (valuef) tags (these are created because of elementB's not having elementC as a child).

Where am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: For your snippets of XML and XSLT the result I get with http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVC is simply an empty `<newElement/>` element. So consider to edit the question and provide an XML input for which you get  the output you say you get.

Comment: Done- Thanks and sorry for not supplying an indented code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map each `elementC` to a `valuef` then you can simply use

```
    <xsl:for-each select="elementB[@attB='valueb']/elementC">
       <valuef>                  
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </valuef>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

that way for the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <root>
      <elementA>
         <elementB attB="valueb">
            <elementC attC="c-value">
               what I want
            </elementC>
         </elementB>
         <elementB attB="valueb">

         </elementB>
      </elementA>
</root>
```

the output is

```
<newElement>
   <valuef>
               what I want
            </valuef>
</newElement>
```

see http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVC/1.

Comment: Thanks, but no- this is different than what I need.
In addition- for record not including the section of interest- your code creates redundant (empty) records too.

Comment: I don't get any empty records for the input in your question.